# Cant read string from registry

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have a problem :(

```
bool LoadStorePath(std::wstring &storePath)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    DWORD key = 0;
    LONG result;
    unsigned long type, size=sizeof(DWORD);
    result = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion",0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE,&hKey);
    if(result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        result = RegQueryValueExW(hKey,L"CryStore",NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&storePath,&size);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return storePath.empty();
}
```

String in registry is "D:\CryptStore"
This code need to read string from registry but in doesnt. Im trying to debug and found after calling RegQueryValueExW size is 28 i think its a my strings len but why its not writed to storePath param?

Regards!

Comment: What's in `storePath` after the call to `RegQueryValueExW()` ?

Comment: Nothing (capacity = 7). But i found some interesting. result is 234 (ERROR_MORE_DATA). So as i understand size of storepath is to small. How to extend its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your variable size contains the wrong value. From the [MSDN article on RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about the size parameter:

> A pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. When the function returns, this variable contains the size of the data copied to lpData.

It seems to be incorrect in your code as you have `size=sizeof(DWORD)` which will obviously be too small to contain the path you try to fetch, as you noticed with `size` being 28 *after* the call, 28 being the size of the data to be read (and it explains the `ERROR_MORE_DATA` which is pretty much self explanatory I think).

You should rework a bit your code to pass a correct size and a buffer of this size.

Answer (score 0):

I think fourth parameter should be REZ_SZ in RegQueryValueEx